# Android Material Design Item selection

Tags: android, multi-select

As mentioned in this [link](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/selection.html#selection-item-selection)

> **Gestures:**
>
> - When initiating selection, both long-press and two-finger touch may    be extended using a drag gesture to select multiple items. Items
>     between the beginning and end points of the drag will be included in
>     the selection.
> - On desktop, a drag originating outside the bounds of all items may    initiate multi-selection (for example, beginning a drag in the left
>     margin of a list, and extending down and to the right to select list
>     items).

We can use drag to select multiple items. I want to do the same using RecyclerView.

How can i do this? Can you give me detailed example of this.

Comment: Added text quote from actual link in case it changes.

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Comment: i found this link https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview very useful for my question....thanx every one to not giving any answer

Comment: That was one hell of a reply!